# Where are the SAFFIRE-I results?

Tags: iss, spacecraft, space-station, life-support

There was a bit of fanfare for the SAFFIRE-I experiment. I got excited...

http://www.nasa.gov/mission_pages/station/research/experiments/1761.html

So they set fire to a Cygnus module before de-orbit. Awesome! Now... why can't I seem to find anything about the actual experiment? Some results?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The experiment hasn't been done yet. [Cygnus OA-6 is still docked to the ISS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_unmanned_spaceflights_to_the_International_Space_Station), it's planned to be undocked in June 2016, that's when the experiment will take place.